# How to count sentences in <textarea>?

Tags: php

I have a textarea on page with UTF8 encoding.

How to count all sentences with php?

**Update:**
Sentence starts with a capital letter and ending by dot, question or exclamation mark.

Comment: How do you define a sentence?

Comment: Well `count(explode('.',rtrim($str,'.')))` seems like a good place to start...

Comment: @Ilya: I made this comment to make you think a bit more about this complicated topic. A good sentence detection requires some sort of intelligence that is aware of context. Though if you constrain the input you can use simpler methods. Your definition gives some constraint but you also have to force the user to some form of writing that prohibits "false positives". So before getting into this field it is good to ask: Why would you want to do this? Maybe there is a better way without counting such complex things as sentences.

Answer (score 3):

As Nobody was saying already, it depends on how you define a sentence. Is it a  ? Is it a linebreak? Is it a capital?
I think it's really hard to define "a sentence", because for every definition you can think of 100 exceptions to that rule.

Anyway, if you come up with a definition, you could thus count the occurences of that in your textarea. Such as the number of linebreaks, the number of dots or the number of capital letters. Or combine all of those into one definition. So basically, just take the contents of your textarea and process some function on it. :-)

That's the best that can be answered to this question imo.

**Edit** After your edit my answer is:

```
function starts_with_upper($str) {     
     $chr = mb_substr ($str, 0, 1, "UTF-8");     
     return mb_strtolower($chr, "UTF-8") != $chr; 
} 

//Get sentences splitted by a dot and starting with a capital letter.
$total = 0;
$sentences = explode('.', rtrim($text, '.'));
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sentences); $i++) {
    $sentence = $sentences[i];
    if (starts_with_upper($sentence)) {
        $total++;
    }
}

echo "You have " . $total . " sentences ending in a dot.
```

Answer (score 3):

From PHP's point of view, a `<textarea>` is simply another `<input>`, so it will be available through `$_GET` or `$_POST` as normal when the form is submitted.

Sentence counting in itself is quite complicated - you could count the number of sentences by the number of periods (`.`) in the text, but this would fail with abbreviations e.g. `e.g.`. You could do so by counting the number of periods followed by a space and then a capital letter, but this would fail for abbreviations followed by common nouns, and also for people who don't use capital letters at the beginning of their sentences. You could decide an average sentence length (say 70 characters) and approximate `sentences = characters/70`. None of these solutions are perfect (or even good, in my opinion).

**UPDATE:** Following your updated question, the following should be helpful:

```
<?php
preg_match_all("/(^|[.!?])\s*[A-Z]/",$_POST['textarea'],$matches);
$count = count($matches);
```

Comment: (Note that this only works for A-Z capitals, and excludes characters such as Ä, I think.)

Answer (score 1):

If you treat sentence as a piece of words with dot at the end you can count dots in your text.

If you use new line, count `\n`'s.