# PHP display sentences up to 100 characters

Tags: php, freebase

My PHP script calls the Freebase API and outputs a paragraph which I then do a little bit of regex and other parsing magic on and return the data to the variable `$paragraph`. The paragraph is made up of multiple sentences. What I want to do is return a shorter version of the paragraph instead.

I want to display the first sentence. If it is less than 100 characters then I'd like to display the next sentence until it is at least 100 characters.

How can I do this?

Comment: A quick way to do it and would probably work for most cases is grab the first 100 characters and decrement until you find a period.

Comment: @VaughanHilts This will return the max sentences to total 100 characters or less - the OP is asking for **at least** 100.

Comment: Grab a substring of length 100, and check if there's a period. If not, grab 99. Period as the last char? If not, go again. Keep decrementing until you see a period.

Comment: I apologize - so find the indexes(s) of all periods, and then use that as your base.

Comment: Yes, use strpos at the first match. If it's not even past 100, move on. If it is, that's acceptable and you're good to go.

Comment: Hope there's no *Mr.*, *Mrs*, *Dr.*, or *e.g.* in there...

Comment: @JaredFarrish I thought of this cases... I can't think of an easy way around it, though. :( A sentence can have a lot of weird cruft.

Comment: @VaughanHilts - You can [work around it to a degree](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7888875/451969).

Comment: @JaredFarrish Indeed - the defintion of a sentence is very loose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for this. You can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) with an offset of 99 to find the first period at or after position 100 - and [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to grab up to that length.

```
$shortPara = substr($paragraph, 0, strpos($paragraph, '.', 99) + 1);
```

You probably want to add a bit of extra checking in case the original paragraph is less than 100 characters, or doesn't end with a period:

```
// find first period at character 100 or greater
$breakAt = strpos($paragraph, '.', 99);
if ($breakAt === false) {
    // no period at or after character 100 - use the whole paragraph
    $shortPara = $paragraph;
} else {
    // take up to and including the period that we found
    $shortPara = substr($paragraph, 0,  $breakAt + 1);
}
```